# Implementing the title under image in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

Implementing the title under the image in UICollectionView. I am new in this ios application development. I want to implement the title under the image view in collectionView. Does anybody know the answer?
I have initialized the label programmatically and add it in the collectionview but it did not show the title

```
 #import "ViewController.h"

 @interface ViewController ()    
 @end

 @implementation ViewController

 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";
    //MARK:-To set the variables
     self.imageArray=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1.png",@"2.png",@"3.jpeg",@"4.jpeg",@"1.png",@"2.png",@"3.jpeg",@"4.jpeg"];
     self.imageText=@[@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8"];
    // for image 

     UIImageView *recipeImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
     recipeImageView.frame = self.collectionView.bounds;
     [self.collectionView addSubview:recipeImageView];
     recipeImageView.tag = 100;
    // for the label

     UILabel *title=[[UILabel alloc]init];
     title.tag = 200;
     [self.collectionView addSubview:title];

     [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier];

 }    

//MARK:-To set the number of sections in UICOLLECTIONVIEW

 - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
     return self.imageArray.count;
 }

//MARK:-To set the content to the UICollectionView

 - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
     static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

     UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

     //MARK:-To set the image dynamically to the UICollectionViewCell

     UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
     recipeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    [self.view addSubview:recipeImageView];
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[self.imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

   //MARK:- To set the label dynamically to the UICollectionViewCell

    UILabel *imageTitle=(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:200];

    [imageTitle setText:self.imageText];            
    return cell;     
 }

 @end
```

Comment: where are you setting frame of label?

Comment: i am not adding as programatically. i used drag and drop method. then what should i do now..?

Comment: then why are you alloc/initing it?

Comment: its an example program. if there are a lot of images and i needed to add the label and image dynamically. the images are adding but the label \

Comment: can you add screen shot of that screen?

Comment: i worked out it and i got the results

Comment: i will give the solution to this problem